# Python Pandas new dataframe column with group by and condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas dataframe that looks as follows.

```
player  count1  count2
A       1       1
A       2       1
A       3       1
A       4       2
A       5       2
B       1       1
B       2       2
B       3       2
B       4       2
```

Column `player` contains names, `count1` is a cumulative sum and column `count2` contains other counts.

I now want to create a new column that contains the value of `count1` where the column `count2` first contains the value `2`.

Hence, the result should look like this:

```
player  count1  count2  new
A       1       1       4
A       2       1       4
A       3       1       4
A       4       2       4
A       5       2       4
B       1       1       2
B       2       2       2
B       3       2       2
B       4       2       2
```

I tried to do it with `transform`, but I cannot figure out how to combine it with the condition based on the `count2` column (and the tanking the value of the `count1` column).

Without the `groupby` it works like this, but I don't know where and how to add the `groupby`:

```
df['new'] = df.loc[matches['count2'] == 2, 'count1'].min()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) by `Series`:

```
s = df[df['count2'] == 2].drop_duplicates(['player']).set_index('player')['count1']

df['new'] = df['player'].map(s)
print (df)
  player  count1  count2  new
0      A       1       1    4
1      A       2       1    4
2      A       3       1    4
3      A       4       2    4
4      A       5       2    4
5      B       1       1    2
6      B       2       2    2
7      B       3       2    2
8      B       4       2    2
```

**Detail**:

First filter only `2` rows by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
print (df[df['count2'] == 2])
  player  count1  count2
3      A       4       2
4      A       5       2
6      B       2       2
7      B       3       2
8      B       4       2
```

And then remove dupes by `player` column by [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
print (df[df['count2'] == 2].drop_duplicates(['player']))
  player  count1  count2
3      A       4       2
6      B       2       2
```

Comment: @beta then use merge with left join like df. merge(df[df['count2'] == 2].drop_duplicates(['player']), on='player', how='left' )